# Firebase Push Notification From PHP MYSQL Server Doesn't Work on Multiple Device

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to send notification on Android devices using MySql PHP Server and Firebase. Firebase tokens are retrieved successfully on my DB but when I try to send notification to all devices from php, it send to the first device saved on my db.

I am here posting the PHP code, I analyzed it a bit but the code is done for one firebase token.

```
function sendPushNotification()  {
require "init.php";
$message="Notification Details";
$title="Notification Title";

$url='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key="MY_FIREBASE_KEY";
$sql="select fcm_token from fcm_info";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$key=$row[0];

$headers=array(
'Authorization:key ='.$server_key,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$fields=array('to'=>$key,'notification'=>
array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message));

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4); 

$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($curl_session); 
mysqli_close($con);}
```

Later I tried changing a little bit, querying all tokens from DB and making assoc array and then pass that array as the key. In that case notification doesn't send and gives me an error saying

`"to" must be json`

Comment: You know that there is a documentation how json's send to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` should looks like? ... `to` is for single message (so you can use it in, difficult word ahead, **loop** ) ... if you need send multiple messages at the same time - read the docs (I bet on `registration_ids`)

Comment: Your above code just fetches a single records from the query results. Loop through the results if you want to send all users a notification.

Comment: Can you expound more on oyur scenario? Are you trying to send the same message notification to all of the devices? If so, why not just make use of Topic Messaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Selvin said, I solved my problem using `registration_ids` instead of `to` .